# Quickly switching between groups in Firefox4

Tags: firefox

Firefox4 (current beta), with which I'm playing around these days has introduced a new tab organizing feature, called groups. Basic idea is simple; instead of having them all in one pile, you separate them, so your chaos is now neatly organized into groups.

Just one thing bothers me - ***I cannot quickly switch between groups with a keyboard shortcut. Anyone knows a way how to do that? Or some custom extension (which I've also not been able to find)?***

Answer (score 3):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> works for me in the released version, and jumps to whichever tab you happened to have had open last in each group. I've not found anything in the help or support documentation that covers this, and someone has [raised](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/804039) on their help forum that this seems to be [undocumented](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts).

Additionally, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> will pull up the tab group view. This is the equivalent action to clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd> do that ?</s>

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> allows you to switch between changes.

(The keybindings have changed from the time this answer was posted to now)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JeffF. The keybindings have changed from the time this answer was posted to now, updated